# How can I make a span and an input sit next to each other and collectively take up 100% of the width of the containing div?

Tags: html, css

I have the following snippet:

```
<html>
<body>
<div style="width: 700px;">
<span>test</span>
<input style="width: 100%;"></input>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But this doesn't do what I want. I wanted that span and input together would account for 100% of the div i.e. that input would start right where the span ends and fill until the width of the div, without breaking to the next line. How do I do that?

Comment: In general, this is not doable with CSS if you want both items to have fluid widths. Also, consider: what should happen if one or both elements (together) have content that does not fit into 700px?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you need **proper fluid width**:

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/kxEML/

**CSS:**

```
.inputContainer {
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px dashed #f0f
}
.inputContainer label {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background: #ccc
}
.inputContainer div {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.inputContainer input {
    width: 100%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="inputContainer">
    <label>test</label>
    <div><input /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: that works when label is before input but not after input...try it out with that fiddle

Answer (score 4):

Of course it does not work. You input takes all the 700px.

```
<div style="width: 700px;">
<span style="width:20%">test</span>
<input style="width: 80%;"></input>
</div>
```

That should work better.

Answer (score 4):

Just set them so their width totals around 100% and `float` them next to each other. In your snippet, the `input` takes up 100% of the div, so the span has to go above it. In order for them to be able to wit on the same line, they have to have a total length of less than 100% or 700px to fit in the div. Setting the `float` property tell the browser to both make them as flush left as possible, and since they can fit, they end up next to each other on the same line. :D

```
<html>
<body>
<div style="width: 700px;">
<span style="width: 49%; float: left; background-color: blue;">test</span>
<input style="width: 49%; float: left; background-color: green;"></input>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `width:100%` for `input` will make it `700px`. Adding the required width of the text, make the row biggest, as a result the `input` goes to the next line. So you could change the `width` of `input` to `95%` to fit the line.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/q75C8/

An alternative solution, using jQuery could be the following:

```
$("input").width(($("div").width()-10)-$("span").width());
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/q75C8/2/

P.S Remove `</input>`, is not required.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

    div { width: 700px; }

    label { display: block; text-align: right; }

    label > input { width: 50%; }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>

<label for="user-name">User Name: <input name="user" id="user-name" /></label>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Using a LABEL instead of a SPAN makes it work smoothly for the blind.

Setting "display: block" on the LABEL makes it expand to 100% of the width of its container (the DIV), and start on a line by itself.

Setting "width: 50%" on the INPUT makes it take up half of the LABEL's width.

The "text-align: right" makes the label's text sit flush against the beginning of the INPUT.

EDIT: Oh, and note that the FOR attribute of the LABEL refers to the ID of the INPUT, not to its NAME.  Edited example to clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">

.left {
  float:left;
  width:15%;
  margin:0px auto;
  padding:0px;
}

.right {
  float:right;
  width:85%;
  margin:0px auto;
  padding:0px;
}

.clearthis {
  width:100%;
  margin:0px auto;
  padding:0px;
  clear:both;
}

</style>
<body>
<div style="width: 700px;">
    <div class="left">
        <span>test</span>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <input style="width: 100%;"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="clearthis"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

something like this should work

Answer (score 0):

I got it using tables:

```
<html>
<body>
<div style="width: 700px;">
  <table border="0" style="width: 100%;">
  <tr>
  <td><span>test</span></td>
  <td style="width: 100%;"><input style="width: 100%;"></input></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh, please, no. We've seen this movie before, and it ends badly.  I direct your attention to: http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/everything.html

Comment: I know, but you've got to do what you've got do to :-) But there's a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Div and CSS is to use the table :

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><span>Username</span></td>
<td><input id="username" name="username" value="" type="text" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Username">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span>Password</span></td>
<td><input id="password" name="password" value="" type="password" placeholder="Password">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<button type="submit">Login</button>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This will work but should be avoided if you want a responsive layout.