# How to make input type file and input type submit at the same line in css?

Tags: css

I want my form to have an input type file and submit on the same line. How to do this?

This is my code :

```
<center>
    <form class = "search" action = "regex.php" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
        <input type = "file" name = "file_upload" />
        <input type = "submit"/>
    </form>
</center>
```

This is how it currently looks:

[image: current image]

I want to be like this, instead:

[image: picture sample that i want]

Comment: You could use this ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470682/html-form-make-inputs-appear-on-the-same-line
or this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526970/how-can-i-make-a-span-and-an-input-sit-next-to-each-other-and-collectively-take

Comment: The input type file and input type submit are already shown inline from the code you provide. Maybe you can provide some more code?